# Check if renaming of a folder is successful by using a batch file

Tags: c#, batch-file, rename

I have a batch to rename folder. How would I know if the renaming is successful as I will not be present there always. My batch file is as follows:

```
@echo off
ren "C:\Program Files (x86)\Application Folder" "AppFolder"
```

I am using C# code to run it using `Process.Start();` Thanks for help.

Comment: check for exit Code of process...

Comment: If you won't be present there, you would have to send an email or sms on failure I suppose...

Comment: how would you *want* to know that it failed?

Comment: You might also consider not using a batch file: System.IO.File.Move

Comment: exit code should be 0 if renaming is successful

Comment: we are performing a lengthy process...everything written in batch. I dont know, I will ask management to go for C# language rather than batch file if it creates problem and tough to maintain

Comment: @Sandy, just kinda seems senseless since you are running the batch file in C# anyway, but you can do what's in that batch file directly in native C#. It's not about hard to maintain, just mainly an observation because you are adding another entity to your process when it's unneeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am very new in batch file processing. And its a privilege to help someone.

```
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\MyBatchFile.bat";
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        // Check if renaming is successful.
        if (process.ExitCode != 0)
        {
            // Renaming failed.
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check the rename *in the Batch file*, just do this:

```
@echo off
ren "C:\Program Files (x86)\Application Folder" "AppFolder"
if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (
   echo RENAME FAILED!
)
```

If you want to check the rename in C#, I suggest you to do the rename in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `Exit Code` of the process instance after calling it. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could always just do it inside c# rather than calling out to a batch file.
See [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) Then you can just catch any exceptions that might throw...

Comment: have seen this answer in many places but truly not convinced. Suppose I tried moving it and it moves successfully, then should I move it back and rename it....I feel renaming is something that OP is looking for....

Comment: If you can do it in c# do it in c#

Comment: but OP is talking about using a batch file.....and yes your solution is fine for C#